# Displaying field wise records from mysql by php?

Tags: php, mysql, record

Hi i have table in mysql like this:

[image: First table]

to show this by php like this:

[image: Second table]

now first i get and print all gradeid on top by this

```
$qry = "select * from grademaster";  
$result= mysql_query($qry,$link);
$nro=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $gradeid = $row['gradeid'];
    echo "<th> $gradeid </th>";
    $grdid[] = $gradeid; ////////takes all grades in array
}
```

and then getting all details from the below table
and but i can't able to show records like on top how can i show this plz help

Comment: For starters, what is $link? Are you getting anything in your echo?

Comment: have u craeted proper HTMl tage before echoing, "echo "<th> $gradeid </th>";" also what is the out out of your $result it is quite possible it is empty so give me dump so i can see what it is outputing

Comment: i've used proper html but i can't understand how can i show grade qty by gradeid

Comment: from proper html i mean that have u echoed something like this echo "<table>"; along with its ending tag, and then do Print_r($result); so that we can see its dump

Comment: i've done completed ... without any help lolzz

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste it instead of your code, then run script in browser.
You'll see the table. Prettify it via CSS and you are done.

I've tested it on my local server and it seems to work.

```
$qry = "select * from grademaster";
$result = mysql_query($qry, $link);

$nro = mysql_num_rows($result);
$table = array();
$rowNum = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $table[$rowNum]['ordid'] = $row['ordid'];
    $table[$rowNum]['orddate'] = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['orddate']));
    $table[$rowNum]['1001'] = intval($row['gradeid']) == 1001 ? $row['ordqty'] : '';
    $table[$rowNum]['1002'] = intval($row['gradeid']) == 1002 ? $row['ordqty'] : '';
    $table[$rowNum]['1003'] = intval($row['gradeid']) == 1003 ? $row['ordqty'] : '';
    $table[$rowNum]['1004'] = intval($row['gradeid']) == 1004 ? $row['ordqty'] : '';
    $table[$rowNum]['1005'] = intval($row['gradeid']) == 1005 ? $row['ordqty'] : '';
    $rowNum++;
}

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ordid</th>
        <th>orddate</th>
        <th>1001</th>
        <th>1002</th>
        <th>1003</th>
        <th>1004</th>
        <th>1005</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($table as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['ordid']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['orddate']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['1001']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['1002']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['1003']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['1004']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['1005']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```